# CSS files are included without HTTPS

Tags: 7, ssl

My full site is using SSL for all pages, and working fine.

But I noticed CSS files are included without HTTPS prefix, while I have set the base URL in my settings.php file as:

```
$base_url = 'https://my.domain.name';
```

How can I include all CSS files with HTTPS?

Comment: AdvAgg has an option to fix that if installing it is an option?

Comment: Yes i can install AdvAgg, But i am really interested to know the reason ?

Comment: It must be some bug introduced by a module, since I've checked it on a site I'm developing and it generates all css files with https.

Comment: Drupal core doesn't do that out of the box so I'd suspect some combination of the custom/contrib modules you have installed is causing it

Comment: Thanks  Елин Й and Clive, i will try to find-out the exact snippet of code and update. till than i will use  AdvAgg as per suggestions.

Comment: Please try this patch, I think it can solve your issue.  https://www.drupal.org/files/cdn-build_css_cache_https-1212184-5.patch

Comment: Would be good to know how the CSS has been added e.g by custom modules or themes? Are you adding a css file from external source via `http`? It is not a fault of Drupal core sure.